# Partial derivatives of an implicit equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Looking for an easy way to find partial derivatives of an implicit equation. For example:

Find $\partial z/\partial x$ and $\partial z/\partial y$ if $z$ is defined implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y$ by the equation
$$x^3+y^3+z^3+6xyz=1$$

**Alternate Approach:**

```
Clear[x, y, z]; 
eqn = x^3 + y^3 + z[x, y]^3 + 6 x y z[x, y] == 1;
Solve[D[eqn, y], D[z[x, y], y]] /. z[x, y] -> z
```

But I still like what I see on this page better.

Comment: Find another approach, but I still like all of your approaches better. See my original post.

Comment: Actually, that approach is quite nice; you now have an explicit reminder that `z` is the dependent variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eqn = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 6 x y z - 1 == 0
Solve[Dt[eqn, x], Dt[z, x]] /. Dt[y, x] -> 0
Solve[Dt[eqn, y], Dt[z, y]] /. Dt[x, y] -> 0
```

If `y` is function of `x`, just do:

```
Solve[Dt[eqn, x], Dt[z, x]]
Solve[Dt[eqn, y], Dt[z, y]]
```

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{-x^2-y^2 \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}-2 x z \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}-2 y z}{2 x y+z^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =\frac{x^2 \left(-\frac{\partial \
x}{\partial y}\right)-2 y z \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}-2 x \
z-y^2}{2 x y+z^2}$$

Comment: How is this different from the solution I posted?

Comment: You set `Dt[y,x]` to zero, and `Dt[z, y]` is missing

Comment: Yes, and we are taking *partial* derivatives, no? We are, per OP, considering $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Also, I left something for the OP to do by himself, so I left out the derivative with respect to the other variable.

Comment: Ok, if you think my answer does not add any value, I can delete it.

Comment: I wasn't asking you to delete your answer; that's entirely your call. I'm just asking if your approach is qualitatively different from mine.

Comment: My approach is not qualitatively different from yours

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero. I like all of the answers I see on this page. I think this particular arrangement is a little easier to understand for students just beginning to use Mathematica. But I want to thank everyone for their help.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Solve[0 == Dt[x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 6 x y z - 1, x] /.
      Dt[y, x] -> 0, Dt[z, x]][[1, 1]]
   Dt[z, x] -> (-x^2 - 2 y z)/(2 x y + z^2)
```

The procedure is similar for the other independent variable.

Comment: I like your solution. I do not understand now why I do not get the same answer as your solution. So I assume I am doing something wrong by solving for z and then taking derivative. So will delete my answer since I need to check why it is different.

Comment: @Nasser, that approach ought to generate something correct, albeit complicated. I'll look at it myself later.

Comment: They are not the same. Since in your method, you set `Dt[y,x]` to zero as you assumed that `y` is not function of `x`.  There is no corresponding action done when one just solves for `z` and then take derivative of the result w.r.t `x`.  That is why the expression I got was much more complicated. I assume your method is what one should do, as the result you obtain is much simpler ;)

Comment: Well, if you use `D[]`, anything that doesn't involve the target variable becomes zero, so it is supposed to be equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

Application of the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) in this case shows that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}/\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} $ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}/\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} $, where $f(x,y,z)=0$ is the implicit function.

```
f = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 6 x y z - 1;
-D[f, {{x, y}}]/D[f, z] // Simplify
```

> ```
> {-((x^2 + 2 y z)/(2 x y + z^2)), -((y^2 + 2 x z)/(2 x y + z^2))}
> ```

Comment: This will come in handy once we do the chain rule and I can explain the implicit function theorem. Thanks.